# Toggle slide with jquery

Tags: javascript, css, slidetoggle, article

I have the following javascript that allows my page visitors to click on a link and display the entire content of an article , like "read more" and when you click it, the entire article is displayed below.

What I want is that when you click "read more", the article to slide down not just appear.

Thank you guys in advance.

HTML

```
<p>The text that is shown by default.<a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">Read more</a></p>
      <div id="example" class="more">
         <p>The rest of the article</p>
         <p><a href="#" id="example-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">Hide this content.</a></p>
```

CSS

```
.more {
      display: none;
      border-top: 1px solid #666;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #666; }
   a.showLink, a.hideLink {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #336699;
      padding-left:20px;
      background: transparent url(down.gif) no-repeat left; }
   a.hideLink {
      background: transparent url(up.gif) no-repeat left; }
   a.showLink:hover, a.hideLink:hover {
      border-bottom: 1px dotted #36f; }
```

JavaScript

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function showHide(shID) {
   if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
      if (document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display != 'none') {
         document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
      }
      else {
         document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'inline';
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your HTML is not full, Show whole HTML!

Comment: @LShetty That's why ask OP to post full HTML! This is a bit confusing

Comment: possible duplicate of [Slidetoggle or slideup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508105/slidetoggle-or-slideup)

Comment: @DhavalMarthak  Sorry, I did not mark as **code** the HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery, you can do:

```
$(function () {
    $('.showLink').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#example').slideToggle();
    });

    $('.hideLink').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#example').slideUp();
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u7gXj/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the title of your question, jQuery makes such animations much easier (because someone already went through and coded the details).

You could try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showHide(shID) {
        if ($('#shID').length) {
            var isDown = $('#shID').data('isDown')?false:true;
            $('#shID'+(isDown?"":"-show")).slideDown('slow');
            $('#shID'+(isDown?"-show":"")).slideUp('slow');
        }
    }
</script>
```