# How to disable function on click event?

Tags: jquery

I have a button which toggle 2 divs. And a function which do the same thing after 5 seconds. But when the user click on the button, the function also works. How can I disable the function when the button is clicked?

This is what I want:
If click on .turn-button, disable function show_back.

My code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    // Toggle
    $(".toggle-class").hide();

    $(".turn-button").click(function() {
        $(".toggle-class").slideToggle(500);
        $(".toggle-class-back").slideToggle(500);
    }); 

    // Show back after 7 seconds
    $(function(){
       function show_back(){
            $(".toggle-class").slideToggle(500);
            $(".toggle-class-back").slideToggle(500);
       };
       window.setTimeout( show_back, 5000 ); // 5 seconds
    });

});
```

Comment: May be you need to call `clearTimeout()`.

Comment: I would replace `slideToggle()` with `slideUp()` & `slideDown()` to give you more control on to show the element or not.

Comment: @MehrdadDastgir why to replace slideToggle?

Comment: @Thinker how to use that?

Comment: @can slideToggle will toggle (show/hide) based on wether the element is showing or not.  Your method show_back() explicitly wants to show the element hence it's more semantically correct to use slideDown. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508105/when-to-use-slidetoggle-or-slideup-slidedown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use .off() function to disable click event

```js
$("p").on("click", function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "red");
  $("#clicked").html("clicked");
});
$("button").click(function() {
  $("p").off("click");
  $("#clicked").html("disabled");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <p> Test Data</p>
  <div id="clicked"></div>

  <button>Click</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Click this paragraph to change its background color and changed div text to clicked.

Click the button below and then click on this paragraph (the click event is removed).

Answer (score 1):

you could try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var clicked = false;
    // Toggle
    $(".toggle-class").hide();

    $(".turn-button").click(function() {
        clicked = true;
        $(".toggle-class").slideToggle(500);
        $(".toggle-class-back").slideToggle(500);
    }); 

    // Show back after 7 seconds
    $(function(){
       function show_back(){
            if(!clicked){   
                $(".toggle-class").slideToggle(500);
                $(".toggle-class-back").slideToggle(500);
            }
       };
       window.setTimeout( show_back, 5000 ); // 5 seconds
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `clearTimeout();`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Toggle
    $(".toggle-class").hide();
    var Timer = setTimeout( show_back, 5000 ); // 5 seconds
    $(".turn-button").click(function() {
        clearTimeout(Timer);
        $(".toggle-class , .toggle-class-back").slideToggle(500);
    }); 
});

// show back function
function show_back(){
    $(".toggle-class , .toggle-class-back").slideToggle(500);
};
```